# Filtering and applying arthimetic expression in pandas data frame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column named volume in a pandas data frame and I wanted to look back previous 5 volumes from current column # and find 40 percentile . 
Volume data - as follows

```
1200
3400
5000
2300
4502
3420
5670
5400
4320
7890
8790
```

For 1st 5 values we don’t have enough data to look back , but from 6th value `3420`  we should find percentile (40) of previous 5 volumes `1200,3400,5000,2300,4502` and keep doing this for rest of the data by taking previous 5 data from current value.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if I understand correctly since there is no mcve

However, sounds like you want a rolling quantile

```
>>> s.rolling(5).quantile(0.4)
```

```
0        NaN
1        NaN
2        NaN
3        NaN
4     2960.0
5     3412.0
6     4069.2
7     4069.2
8     4429.2
9     4968.0
10    5562.0
dtype: float64
```